# HTML text input plugin for CSV data preserving column alignment?

Tags: html, csv, tabs

When pasting CSV data into an HTML text area, or in all the jquery rich text editors I could find, data is visually "messed up": columns alignment is lost, in particular when a cell is long and the one below is very short.

Is anyone aware of some kind of plugin similar to a text area that would *visually* preserve columns alignment when pasting some CSV data into it? That would require interpreting the tabs as columns separators, and not just as a fixed number of spaces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script to replace the tabs for celltags and the newlines for rowtags like:

```
r='foo\tbar\tfoobar\nbar\tfoo\tfoobar\nfoobar\tbar\tfoo';

r = r.replace(/\n/g,'</td></tr><tr><td>');
r = r.replace(/\t/g, '</td><td>');
r = '<table><tr><td>' + r + '</td></tr></table>';
alert(r);
```

Comment: Hi, I was searching for a solution doing that with the pasted text inside the textarea directly, but your solution is fine, thanks.